# Compare Bytes From Data Stored in a std::string

Tags: c++

Hopefully, I can explain this reasonably enough.

I have a string that is the hex representation of an image file. The data comes from a network stream and then is written to a file but before it is written to the file via `write()` it is stored in a string such like:

```
std::string mystr = "ffd8ffe000104a464946043c87b6e...21451457af4e2b91686e92b1ffd9";
```

Now the real string, of course, is actually 10k characters but the important info is the `ffd8` at the beginning and `ffd9` at the end. Yes a JPEG, but the data could be PNG or GIF as well.

What do I need to do to convert the string into something useable so that I can do comparisons like

```
if (mystr[0] == '\xff' && mystr[1] == '\xd8') {
   ..
}
```

Clearly, I cannot index into the string object that way because `mystr[0]` is 'f' right?

Do I need to convert the string into a byte array of sorts? Vector of Bytes?

Eventually, I will want to match x length to a series of bytes such as match the above string against `89504E470D0A1A0A` (PNG).

Comment: `std::string` doesn't exist in C.

Comment: If you want to operate on bytes you shouldn't store it as a string

Comment: The only use case I know of where you get a string like this is the AsciiHex encoding that some formats use (like PDF).

Comment: You could write a function to convert the two chars to the byte, for a given index. But maybe it is more useful to store binary data into the `std::string`, and only convert it to/from hex when it should be outputted or inputted that way.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming input is always valid)

Define a small utility to convert a char to its hex interpretation.

```
inline uint8_t char_to_hex(char c)
{
  if(c <= '9') { return static_cast<uint8_t>(c - '0');
  } else if (c <= 'Z') {
    return static_cast<uint8_t>(10 + c - 'A');
  } else {
    return static_cast<uint8_t>(10 + c - 'a');
  }
}
```

Then you can write your own function to extract the byte at a given index.

```
uint8_t at_index(std::string const& str, std::size_t index)
{
  std::size_t real_index = index * 2;

  char lhs = str[real_index];
  char rhs = str[real_index + 1];

  return (char_to_hex(lhs) << 4) | char_to_hex(rhs);
}
```

As you mentioned, you could also transform the string into a vector of bytes.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> to_hex_vec(std::string foo)
{
  std::vector<uint8_t> res(foo.size() / 2);

  for(std::size_t i = 0; i < foo.size(); i += 2)
  {
    res[i / 2] = (char_to_hex(foo[i]) << 4) | char_to_hex(foo[i + 1]);
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: `else if (c <= 'Z')` -- Of course this assumes the collating sequence is ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that:

1) Assumes the string consists of characters 0-9, a-f, only.

2) We have an even number of characters in the string.

3) Byte 0 is the most-significant byte (leftmost).  Adjust this if the opposite is desired.

4) No bounds/error checking is done.

Note that this is one of many ways to do this, and not an illustration of the "best" or fastest method (probably table lookup is faster):

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class StringToHexByte
{
    std::string str;

    char getByteValue(unsigned whichByte) const
    {
       static const char *digits="0123456789abcdef";
       char digit1 = strchr(digits, str[whichByte * 2]) - digits;
       char digit2 = strchr(digits, str[whichByte * 2 + 1]) - digits;
       return (digit1 << 4) | digit2;
    }

    public:
        StringToHexByte(const char *s) : str(s) {}

        char operator[] (unsigned idx) const
        { return getByteValue(idx); }
};

int main()
{
    StringToHexByte stoh("ff89d8");
    char byteValue0 = stoh[0];
    char byteValue1 = stoh[1];
    char byteValue2 = stoh[2];
    if ( byteValue0 == '\xff')
       std::cout << "We got the value of hex ff\n";
    if ( byteValue1 == '\x89')
       std::cout << "We got the value of hex 89\n";
    if ( byteValue2 == '\xd8')
       std::cout << "We got the value of hex d8";
}
```

Output:

```
We got the value of hex ff
We got the value of hex 89
We got the value of hex d8
```